# Error - UIImageView UIScrollView Playing Background Video

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm having trouble getting the following code to compile, any suggestions people?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var avatar: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var contentImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        avatar.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        avatar.layer.borderWidth = 4.0
        avatar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        avatar.clipsToBounds = true
        scrollView.delegate = self
        contentImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginScreen") as! UIViewController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let yOffset = self.scrollView.contentOffset.y * 0.2
        let availableOffset = min(yOffset, 60)
        let contentRectYOffset = availableOffset / contentImageView.frame.size.height
        contentImageView.layer.contentsRect = CGRectMake(0.0, contentRectYOffset, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

**The error is**

> 'Downcast from 'UIViewController?' to 'UIViewController' only unwraps
>   optionals; did you mean to use '!'

**This happens in the line**

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginScreen") as! UIViewController
```

Comment: What's the error? And where is it happening?

Comment: the error is 'Downcast from 'UIViewController?' to 'UIViewController' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!' ----------this happens in the line ----let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginScreen") as! UIViewController

Comment: Update your question with all of the relevant details so people can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are force down casting an object which is already of same type. You just need to remove `as! UIViewController` and assuming the `ViewController` with identifier `LoginScreen` exists, you can force unwrap the `vc` variable when needed.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginScreen")
    self.presentViewController(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks R P, your solution worked a treat.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginScreen")
self.presentViewController(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}

Comment: Glad it helped! if the solution worked, you could mark it answered.